# What am I doing wrong Hooks Related

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to hooks so I will ask this question:

How can I legally use setState inside a onChange function ??

```
  {
    const state = useState([{date: date}]);
  };
```

This throws an error :(

Expected: update the state 
And result error message: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

I did find some answers on the web about multiple React version installed but this is not the case here :)

Comment: can you show me your full code, by the way, Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. It wont work with class components.

Comment: sure: https://pastebin.com/9CGH4kLX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your hook in the body of your main component function:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    // declaring your useState Hook - it returns a getter and setter
    const [date, setDate] = useState(null)

    const myCallback = (newDate)=>{
     // you can read the state
     const state = date;

      // or, you can do the equivalent of setState
       setDate(newDate)
    }

    return // return your .jsx

}
```

The things to note are that you declare your hook *once*, and that it returns two parameters, a getter and a setter. From then on, you interact with that original Hook using the getter and setter only.

For your pastebin code:

```
const [myState,setMyState] = useState(
  {
    name: "",
    type: props.navigation.getParam("serviceName"),
    date: "15-05-2018",
    imageURI: props.navigation.getParam("imageURI")
  });

 const handleChange = e =>  {
   setMyState(prevState=> {...prevState, name: e.nativeEvent.text})
 };
```

(I've used `myState` and `setMyState` but they can be whatever you like)

Comment: The only thing I don't get is how the hell can I declare setMyState now ???

Comment: You declare it once, at the place where you first call `useState`. After that, you just call it.

Comment: if I do ```const setMyState = e =>  {
   [state] =  useState[{ name: e.nativeEvent.text}]
 };
``` it says block scope variable can't be redeclared lol :(

Comment: Again, you can't call useState in an inner function like that. Call it once to set it up, and only at the top level of your component. In case you're confused, useState is not a replacement for setState.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm it seems you've got it wrong...

There's no single state when we use hooks like in the case of a class,

```
const [item, setValue] = useState(null)
```

this sets the state variable "item" with initial value of null. Now we can use the "setValue" to change the value of "item" to what we want like this
setValue(5).There is no setState as in the case of a class component. Since the value of a state variable has been changed the component rerenders. We can declare multiple state-variables like

`const [newitem, setnewItemValue] = useState(null)` and whenever a state-variable changes the component will rerender

Comment: The only thing I don't get is how the hell can I declare setMyState now ??? 
If I do ```const setMyState = e =>  {
   [state] =  useState[{ name: e.nativeEvent.text}]
 };
``` it says block scope variable can't be redeclared lol :(

Comment: @Alessandro you're not following the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: Again there's no setState with hooks
useState returns a state variable and a function to update the state. for example
const [item, setValue] = useState(null) means you can update the state using setValue